# Can not find out the source of data I need when crawling website

Tags: python, web-crawler

I am writing a web crawler with python. I come across a problem when I am trying to find out the source of the data I need.

The site I am crawling is: https://www.whoscored.com/Regions/252/Tournaments/2/England-Premier-League, and the data I want is as below:

[image]

I can find these data by browsering the page source after the page has been tatolly loaded by firefox:

```
DataStore.prime('standings', {  stageId:15151, idx:0, field: 'overall'},     [[15151,32,'Manchester United',1,5,4,1,0,16,2,14,13,1,3,3,0,0,10,0,10,9,7,2,1,1,0,6,2,4,4,[[0,1190179,4,0,2,252,'England',2,'Premier League','2017/2018',32,29,'Manchester United','West Ham','Manchester United','West Ham',4,0,'w'] ......
```

I thought these data should be requested though ajax, but I detected no such request by using the web console.

Then, I simulated the browser behaviour (set header and cookies) requiring the html page:

```
<html>
<head>
<META NAME="robots" CONTENT="noindex,nofollow">
<script src="/_Incapsula_Resource?SWJIYLWA=2977d8d74f63d7f8fedbea018b7a1d05">
</script>
<script>
(function() { 
var z="";var     b="7472797B766172207868723B76617220743D6E6577204461746528292E67657454696D6528293B7661722073746174757......";for (var i=0;i<b.length;i+=2){z=z+parseInt(b.substring(i, i+2), 16)+",";}z =   z.substring(0,z.length-1); eval(eval('String.fromCharCode('+z+')'));})();
</script></head>
<body>
<iframe style="display:none;visibility:hidden;" src="//content.incapsula.com/jsTest.html" id="gaIframe"></iframe>
</body></html>
```

I created an .html file with the content above, and open it with firefox, but it seems that the script did not executed. Now, I don`t know how to do, I need some help, thanks!

Comment: I find that the request is blocked by Incapsula

Comment: So, did you solve your own problem?

Comment: @sadmicrowave  At least I know where the problem is, and I should study the way the bypass Incapsula